# Fill-in task detail from e- mail

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I'm trying to create an InfoPath form that me or my team can fill-in the necessary task information and submit the data into SharePoint Online while sending this form by e-mail to a responsible user to fill-in/complete the rest of the task form (e.g. report there action) which will also submit to the SharePoint list.

I am trying to avoid sending SharePoint list or having users install any software as they do not want to learn anything new :(... So e-mail seems to be the only way because we all have Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your users cannot have any new software installations, e.g.: InfoPath, then [this option](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-infopath-e-mail-forms-in-outlook-113fe7c5-9dfe-4fa8-9c90-8780d5900a57) of integrated InfoPath forms in Outlook is out of bounds for you.

As such, I would suggest that you examine using Outlook organizational forms outlined in this [article](https://o365info.com/create-publish-organizational-forms-office-365/).

Comment: Thank you, never heard of organizational form before. I'll give it a try.